# Reset JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea, windowlistener

I am having 3 `JTextArea` :

```
private static JTextArea area[];
```

The text area has text in it already but I want to add more manually. So when I close the frame the text area gets an update, but it doesn't work.
The frame which contains text area is called `f`. Printing the text of text area after closing the frame works as expected.

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
                area[i].setText(area[i].getText());
                System.out.println(area[i].getText());
            }
        });
```

Comment: Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: What is `i`? Probably you forgot to create a loop over all the textareas?

Comment: No i havent. only the first line is not working . The line with println works good.

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the same text value to the same text area, denoted by the same index i

```
f.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent windowEvent) {
```

**area[i].setText(area[i].getText());**// <--- this line of code has no logic effect

```
System.out.println(area[i].getText()); 

    }
});
```

Probably you will need to set it into some other place, or use different index in one of the arrays;

Comment: No i am not. Lets say the value of area[i] is "Hello". Then i write next to it "World". When i close the frame and reopen it i want the area to be "Hello World"

Comment: @Ben Yes you are. `area[i].setText(area[i].getText());` means: "take everything which is written inside the text area and make the text area display that text". Do as was asked from you and post an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you want that:

```
public class MyFrame extends JFrame {
    private static JTextArea area[];

    static {
        area = new JTextArea[3];
        for(int i = 0; i < area.length; i++) {
            area[i] = new JTextArea();
        }
    }

    public MyFrame() throws HeadlessException {
        super();
        createGUI();
    }

    private void createGUI() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        setLayout(new GridLayout(0, area.length));

        for(JTextArea textArea: area) {
            JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);
            add(scrollPane);
        }

        addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
                for(JTextArea textArea: area) {
                    builder.append(textArea.getText());
                }

                System.out.println(builder.toString());

                for(JTextArea textArea: area) {
                    textArea.setText(builder.toString());
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```